# How to copy file paths including extension into .txt file

Tags: windows, file, cmd

For example in a folder named sample there are 3 images namely *img1.jpg*  & *img2.jpg* & *img3.jpg*

I want to copy all the paths of all images to a `.txt` file

content of .txt will be

```
C:/sample/img1.jpg
C:/sample/img2.jpg
C:/sample/img3.jpg
```

Comment: that only puts the file name to the .txt , it doesn't include its full path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this in your directory that you want to tree. It extends the path name.

> `> "dirs.txt" (for %A in (*) do echo %~fA)`

Edited in regards to [aschipfl's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34489397/5645103)

Answer (score 1):

I would start here: http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html. This link shows how to iterate through files. in the example you can use this and modify for output to a file. 
The second one is a starting point for output.

```
FOR /D /r %G in ("User*") DO Echo We found %G 
FOR /D /r %G in ("User*") DO Echo "We found %G" >> C:\test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dir command with recursion and bare format option like so

```
dir /s /b *.jpg > files.txt
```

Reference:

http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html

Answer (score 0):

[Clayton Wahlstrom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34485874/5047996) is a good start, but it can be improved:

- every single item/line is redirected individually, because the `>>` operator is placed in the body of the `for` loop; however, redirecting all data once would improve the overall performance;
- the used redirection syntax causes every line to contain a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, because there is one before the `>>` redirection operator;
- you need to ensure that `dirs.txt` does not yet exist or is empty initially, because the `>>` redirection appends data if applicable;
- I recommend to use upper-case `for` loop variables, to be able to distinguish them from the `~` modifiers;

To overcome all these issues, just put the entire `for` loop into parentheses `()` and do the redirection `>` once only, like this:

```
> "dirs.txt" (for %A in (*) do echo %~fA)
```